# Banner Ad load failed with test Ad ID on admob android

Tags: android, admob, banner-ads

I was trying to add Admob's Banner ad with test **UnitId** in my app. But it doesn't load on my app. it comes up with Toast message "**Ad load failed!**" that I added into **onAdFailedToLoad()**.
 Here are my codes :

**MainActivity.Java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AdView mAdView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        // Sample AdMob app ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713
        MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");

        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build() ;

        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);


        mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Ad loaded successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Ad load failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                mAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdOpened() {
                // Code to be executed when an ad opens an overlay that
                // covers the screen.
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Ad opens an overlay that covers the screen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLeftApplication() {
                // Code to be executed when the user has left the app.
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User left the app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                // Code to be executed when the user is about to return
                // to the app after tapping on an ad.
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Ad viewed by user!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
```

Here's **activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme"
            app:title="@string/app_name">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tab_text_1" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tab_text_2" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tab_text_3" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />



    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/AdMob_ID"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.a3dwallpaper2018">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="@string/AdMob_ID"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </activity>

                <activity
                    android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
                    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
                    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
            </application>

        </manifest>
```

**Build.gradle(Module:app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.a3dwallpaper2018"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        sourceSets {
            main {
                assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/']
                res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/main/res/drawable']
            }
        }

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.mindorks:placeholderview:0.7.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.1.3'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.2.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:palette-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0 '
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.0.0'

}
```

**Build.gradle(Project: Project_Name)**

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }


    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I've tried so many solutions that I got from the google search but ultimately nothing works. I've found this possible error's from **logcat**.

**One:**

```
Unable to get advertising id: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException: com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzba.zzby
```

**Two :**

```
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
V/FA: onUnbind called for intent. action: com.google.android.gms.measurement.START
V/FA: Local AppMeasurementService is shutting down
```

**Three :**

```
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play Store is missing.
E/FirebaseInstanceId: Google Play services missing or without correct permission.
```

I'm using real device to test my app and it has **Google play services** (Updated) & Google play store (Updated) both. I also tried with **addTestDevice(My device id)** , but it didn't helped.

Comment: there is a code for the error, print it in onAdFailedToLoad it is called "errorCode', and tell us, so we can find the problem

Comment: How can I print the error in onAdFailedToLoad()? @MomenZaqout

Comment: Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Ad load failed!: "+errorCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 1
 W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 1

It comes up with this message @MomenZaqout

Comment: can I see AdMob_ID in your string.xml file?

Comment: I just searched to google now. it may mean "ERROR_CODE_INVALID_REQUEST". I used this (ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713) as AdMob_ID. I tried other test ID's too. but no other code is working.

Comment: see the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error 1 means the ID is wrong.

Admob gives you a number like this and is the app ID, with ~ :

```
ca-app-pub-9611919736642270~3440171884
```

And the unit id with / is to the request;

```
ca-app-pub-9611919736642270/3440171834
```

app id and unit id should be different. in your code seems to be same

here is full official description: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start

you have to get Unit Id from admob and use it in AdMob_ID

Comment: I didn't create real AdMob account till now. Can't I use test ID's for a test?

Comment: try that 
ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111 in AdMob_ID

Comment: I used, 
 ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111 as AdMob_Unit_ID
and
ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 as AdMob_Application_ID

Thanks! It works!